# Novice HTML - Buttons don't work correctly

Tags: html

I'm trying to create my very first HTML code. My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="apply" value="Push Me" onclick="javascript:faa();" />
<input type="button" id="apply" value="No, Push Me Instead" onclick="javascript:foo();"     />
Official website of Foocorp Inc. (Not really.)
</body>
<script type="text/javascipt">
function faa(e)
{

alert('Nope, it is the other button.');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo(e)
{

alert('You have destroyed your computer. Thank you for your time.');
window.close();
}
</script>
</html>
```

Whenever I push the button with value "No, Push Me Instead" it works fine. The button "Push Me" doesn't do anything when I push it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apart from anything else, you've got two elements with the same `id`: this is invalid HTML ("[\[the `id`\] attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)"). Also, remove the `javascript:` from the event-handlers in your HTML, they're entirely unnecessary.

Comment: As you're starting, you should start with best-practices and not with bad habits. Inline javascript is not good. And as pointed by David Thomas, you can't have 2 elements with the same id. I don't think this is the problem, but the first step of debugging is having valid code.

Comment: You've gone and spelt `javascript` wrong in the first function.

Comment: Also, in addition to the above comments, I do not believe it is valid to place a `<script></script>` tag between the `</body>` and `</html>` tags. As far as I know script tags are only supported in the `head` or `body`.

Answer (score 4):

`text/javascipt` should have an `r` in it.

HTML 5 makes the `type` attribute for script elements optional when you are writing JavaScript. When you are dealing with JS, the attribute serves no purpose other then to be an opportunity to make types that break your code so omit it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine when I move the other function to the same script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(e)
    {

        alert('You have destroyed your computer. Thank you for your time.');
        window.close();
    }

        function faa(e)
    {

        alert('Nope, it is the other button.');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change script type spelling, as there is a spelling mistake

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```